# Fake Recycle Bin via Group Policy

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows

Is it possible to create a fake recycle bin where the files aren't actually deleted using MS AD/ Group Policy?

The goal is to be able to recover 'deleted' files after, let's say, a dirty resignation.

Comment: Volume shadow copies? That will help on local drives. Saved me a few times.

Comment: Good idea, looking into how we can deploy this feature with the least possible effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no stock functionality in the product to do what you're looking for. I'm sure somebody could come up with a crazy hack that would give you 85% of what you wanted, but that last 15% to make it work would likely have to involve rather invasive modifications to Windows (or, at least, third-party software). Group Policy will let you run arbitrary code on startup or logon, so making something do what you want that's invoked by Group Policy is certainly possible, but what you want isn't any kind of stock functionality.

You're going about this the wrong way. The files you're looking to "recover" from a "dirty resignation" should already be stored in locations that are covered by your regular backup. Recover of these files should be a matter of restoring a backup. If you're storing important data (files that might need to be "recovered") in a location that's not covered by backup then you've got a lot bigger problems than a "dirty resignation".

Comment: Hi @Evan, makes perfect sense. Backing up files would squash the problem. I've looked into Windows Backup, now rebranded File History but it has limited GPO configurations. I've seen websites recommending the use of Symantec. Any idea?