# Backup Active Directory users' files, deploy via GPO?

Tags: windows, active-directory, backup, group-policy

Am looking for a solution which can be configured to be deployed via group policies. I've looked into **Windows Backup**, but it doesn't fulfill our requirements. We need something like this:

1. Runs silently on user computer as a service.
2. Configured via GPO, and can't be switched off by standard users.

This question is a result of a previous topic posted here: [Fake Recycle Bin via Group Policy](https://serverfault.com/questions/585538/fake-recycle-bin-via-group-policy)

Comment: Don't backup individual end-user devices. Centralize the data and back that up.

Comment: I definitely agree that centralized data is the way to go wherever possible. But there are cases where local data is unavoidable (e.g. virtual machine images) so I would be interested in something like the question is asking for.
I have used robocopy scripts in the past but that isn't ideal.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be storing user data files on client computers. You should be using something like [Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx), which can be configured via Group Policy, to store user data files on server computers (where they can have all kinds of fun redundancies applied to their storage). If your users need access to their files when disconnected from the network (say, on portable computers) you migth consider using the [Offline Files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/understanding-offline-files#1TC=windows-7) feature to *cache* and synchronize copies of files on the hard disk drives of client computers.

My experience has been that no client-side backup "solution" has ever come reached the reliability of just storing user files on server computers.

Comment: Thanks @EvanAnderson. Your answer is clear and well written. Certainly points me into the right direction.